# Template code creates exponential number of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I noticed this strange behaviour with my jQuery code, when it pulled a JSON from an AJAX request to create the elements with a template. What I am trying to do is, with the JSON, which is technically an array of few objects, I am constructing a series of cards, which show something to the user.

I have drilled down the problem to the below code (without using AJAX) and got the issue replicated here as well.

```js
$(function() {
  // Mimicking the AJAX Request.
  // The getJSON gets an array of objects.
  // I am limiting it to just string array, and lenght of 3 to keep things simple.
  var response = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"];
  // My Code.
  $.each(response, function(index, value) {
    $tmp = $(".template").clone();
    $tmp.find("strong").text("Name");
    $tmp.find("span").text(value);
    $tmp.appendTo("body");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.template {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<div class="template">
  <strong>All</strong>
  <span>Names</span>
</div>
```

**Problem**

If you see in the above snippet, you could find that the elements are exponentially increasing. i.e., for the nth element, it displays the cards for n times, starting from one:

```
n   card        desc
--- ---------- -----------------------------------
1   1 card      Alice is displayed only once.
2   2 cards     Bob is displayed two times.
3   4 cards     Charlie is displayed four times.
```

And so on... I could find an amusing series here, which resembles the powers of 2: `1, 2, 4, 8, 16...` (2<sup>0</sup>, 2<sup>1</sup>, 2<sup>2</sup>, 2<sup>3</sup>, 2<sup>4</sup>,... Exponential on 2).

Another strange behaviour that I noticed was, when I use an extra `<div>`, this problem doesn't happen. For e.g., consider the same code, but wrap the template by nesting it into another `<div>` structure:

```js
$(function() {
  // Mimicking the AJAX Request.
  // The getJSON gets an array of objects.
  // I am limiting it to just string array, and lenght of 3 to keep things simple.
  var response = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"];
  // My Code.
  $.each(response, function(index, value) {
    $tmp = $(".extra .template").clone();
    $tmp.find("strong").text("Name");
    $tmp.find("span").text(value);
    $tmp.appendTo("body");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.template {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<div class="extra">
  <div class="template">
    <strong>All</strong>
    <span>Names</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure what exactly is causing the problem here. Is there any crazy mistake that I am doing? `:)`

Comment: You might also want to read about the HTML5 [template tag](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/).

Comment: @StephenP Will do, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is, you are not removing the class `template`, so every time you append, you have double the number of elements with the class `template`, so the first way to do is, when you do the clone, you need to remove the class `template`.

```
$tmp = $(".template").clone().removeClass("template");
```

**Note:** In the below preview I have slightly modified the class, because of styling.

```js
$(function() {
  // Mimicking the AJAX Request.
  // The getJSON gets an array of objects.
  // I am limiting it to just string array, and lenght of 3 to keep things simple.
  var response = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"];
  // My Code.
  $.each(response, function(index, value) {
    // ----------- Change here ---------- //
    $tmp = $(".template").clone().removeClass("template");
    $tmp.find("strong").text("Name");
    $tmp.find("span").text(value);
    $tmp.appendTo("body");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<div class="item template">
  <strong>All</strong>
  <span>Names</span>
</div>
```

The reason why, second time it worked is, you had enclosed the template inside the `extra` div, and you are appending the new `.template`s to the `<body>` directly, so the selector `.extra .template` selects only one. Still this is a mistake because each and every `<div>` you generate bears the `template` class, which ideally shouldn't.

Hope the explanation is clear.

Comment: In fact, I make templates an `id="foo-template` because there is only one, it's not a _class of things_.

Comment: @StephenP That might be dangerous for newbies, as well, since ... wait. Will `.clone()` copy the `ID` as well?

Comment: Without testing -- I think it does and you _do_ still have to remove it.

Comment: @StephenP Sorry mate, it does copy the `id` and make a big crime of duplicating IDs: http://jsbin.com/manenekoli/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Checked too, yes it does dupe the ID, but it's not a violation if you remove the ID before you attach the new node to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the help @PraveenKumar!

Comment: @DakshShah Does it work? Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Sure thing. Thanks again!

Comment: @Praveen if you want to add a summary to your answer of `id` vs. `class` when cloning I'll delete my side of these comments.

Comment: @StephenP You told it. So I don't wanna take credit of this. If you wanna add it in my answer, I'll be very happy... Coz, you told it. `:)` It should not look like I stole your idea right. Or else, let's leave the comments as is here.